# How can I install a window air conditioner and still allow the window to be opened?

Tags: windows, air-conditioning

I want to install a window based air conditioner but still allow for the ability to open the window when needed. I was thinking of using a piece of wood screwed into the window frame to support the air conditioner and prevent it from falling out.

Is that the right way to go about it?

Comment: That kind of defeats the purpose. If you want to open the window, you should just remove the unit and replace it later. It seems like a lot of extra work to install a support just for that purpose.

Comment: Not every time it's warm do I want to turn on the AC, sometimes there's a nice breeze. At the end of summer I take it out, but often at night it's nice to open it to allow a cross breeze.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend window air-conditioner [support brackets](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&docid=Rl8b_GxjAl8ynM&tbnid=a-_y_8vIGr9JZM:&ved=0CAUQjRw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.homedepot.com%2Fp%2FAC-Safe-Universal-Light-Duty-Air-Conditioner-Support-AC-080%2F100091666&ei=PvrqU5wviJ6MApnxgfAL&bvm=bv.72938740,d.cGU&psig=AFQjCNGMQ6vBysEGMkRhnwayqUrrblY_jA&ust=1407994748873973) (or a custom made shelf) whether or not you intend to open the window.